# Привязка команды к клику по строке DataGrid в WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Имеется `DataGrid`, ссылающийся на `ObservableCollection<T>`. `SelectedItem` привязан к свойству во ViewModel. Хочу создать `CustomDataGrid`, в котором будет команда, срабатывающая при двойном клике по одной из строк. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте  EventTrigger. Привяжите к команде из ViewModel

```
<xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"/>
```

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CommandToBindTo}" 
                               CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameterToBindTo}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```